# JQuery not first child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="date-header">2012-06-03</div>
</div>
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="todo">Todo</div>
</div>
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="meeting">meeting</div>
</div>
```

I want to show only the divs of a different class name e.g. class="todo" and keep the "date-header" visible.  I have the following javascript"

```
$('.feed-cluster,.feed-item-container').not('div:first.date-header').not(className).slideUp(speed, function(){
      $('.feed-cluster' + className + ',.feed-item-container' + className).slideDown(speed);
});
```

Everything works fine except the bit where I am trying to exclude the first child with a class name of date-header:

```
.not('div:first.date-header')
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Comment: Take note that there's a significant difference between `:first` and `:first-child`.

Comment: `not('div.date-header:first-child')`

Comment: Because `:first` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `source :` http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 64):

```
$('div.date-header').slice(1);
```

Should do it.

[`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) Is the **fastest** function!

> Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method.

Alternative way, which still uses the  `querySelectorAll` function:

```
$('div.date-header').not(':first');
```

Answer (score 25):

`.not('div:first.date-header')` should be `.not('.date-header:first')`

Answer (score 9):

As @gdoron noted: `:first` is not part of the `css` specification, but [`:not()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) and [`:first-child`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo) are. It is [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) by all major browsers.

So you also could use this to skip the first child using a `css` selector inside `jQuery`.

```js
$(".child:not(:first-child)").css("background-color", "blue");
```

```css
div.child {
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Im a child of .container</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Im a child of .container</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Im a child of .container</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### **legacy browsers support**

---

If you need to support legacy browsers, or if you are hindered by the `:not()` selector. You can use the `.child + .child` selector. Which will also work.

```js
$(".child + .child").css("background-color", "blue");
```

```css
div.child {
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Im a child of .container</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Im a child of .container</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <p>Im a child of .container</p>
  </div>
</div>
```